# Opening onscreen keyboard on button press

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-panel, onboard

Normally you can swipe from the bottom of a touch display to show the onscreen keyboard, but it's disabled on full screen applications.
I noticed that notifications still appear on full screen applications, so would it be possible to make they onscreen keyboard appear when you click on a button (any button will do)?

Comment: Is **onboard**'s floating icon what you want?You can enable it via **Onboard Settings->General->Desktop integration->Show floating icon when Onboard is hidden**

Comment: Another way is to [assign a shortcut](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-on-gnome-shell/) for the command ```onboard```.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Sorry the title had a typo. I meant the integrated onscreen keyboard in GNOME 3.36. Onboard does not work in Wayland and the last stable version was released years ago.